# Degrees of freedom of J-Test distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, method-of-moments

This [book](https://akela.mendelu.cz/~xhavir3/ekm/Heij.pdf) states, on page page 256 ( the GMM section) that the J-test(for over-identifying restrictions) is of the following form $G_n'J_n^{-1}G_n \approx \chi^2(m-p) $, where $G_n=G_n(\theta)=1/n \cdot \sum^n_{i=1}g_i(\theta)$ which are the sample versions of DGP original $m$ distinct moment conditions $E(g_i(\theta_0))=0$.

The author says that this result comes from using $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}G_n\rightarrow_dN(0,J_0)$, and $J_0\approx \frac{1}{n} J_n$.

I'm trying to deduce the degrees of freedom of the chi-squared distribution.

For that I'm using the following result:

Let $y_1,...,y_n\sim N(0,1)$, then if $y=(y_1,...,y_n)'$ and $A$ a symmetric and idempotent $n\times n$ matrix, we have that $y'A y\sim \chi^2(rank(A)) $.

So, we know that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}J_0^{-1/2}G_n(\theta_0)\rightarrow_dN(0,I)$, thus,
$G_n'J_n^{-1}G_n \approx \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}J_0^{-1/2}G_n(\theta_0)\right)'\cdot I\cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}J_0^{-1/2}G_n(\theta_0)\right)\rightarrow_d \chi^2(rank(I))$, where $I$ is an identity matrix of dim $m\times m$.

So, I'm doing something wrong. What is it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Thanks for your interest in this question. The book is "Econometrics Methods with Applications in Business and Economics", Oxford Press.

Comment: You should edit that into the post. I'm not sure I personally can help you, but referencing the book, and ideally the pages or section of the book, will make it easier for anyone to help.

Comment: @ssdecontrol You can find the pdf here: https://akela.mendelu.cz/~xhavir3/ekm/Heij.pdf